# How to set compiler and arch in conanfile.txt?

Tags: c++, conan

How can I set compiler and arch settings in conanfile.txt? I've tried just putting it into

```
[settings]
arch=x86
```

but I'm getting `Unrecognized field: settings`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You might be confusing the `conanfile.txt` with a profile. [Here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html) is a link that explains how to format and use profiles.

A file called `myprofile`:

```
[env]
# Where is our C compiler
CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
# Where is our CPP compiler
CXX=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++

[settings]
# We are building in Ubuntu Linux
os_build=Linux
arch_build=x86_64

# We are cross building to Windows
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
compiler=gcc
# Adjust to the gcc version of your MinGW package
compiler.version=6.3
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
```

You can use it like this:

```
$ conan install --profile /abs/path/to/myprofile  # abs path
$ conan install --profile ./relpath/to/myprofile  # resolved to current dir
$ conan install --profile myprofile  # resolved to user/.conan/profiles/myprofile
```

Comment: Hm I think I get the difference. Thank you ^_^ So I can do `conan install . --profile ./conanprofile.txt`. We need to always use specific profile, so can I somehow set it inside `conanfile.txt` somehow? Our should I just make a `.bat` file for that?

Comment: There are a couple different ways to specify the toolchain. A profile is probably the simplest way to do it. [This](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#cross-building-with-conan) guide lists the other ways. I'm also pretty new to Conan, so idk much

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19811768)

Comment: @Alejandro Updated with examples from reference